# use upper snake case for enum query parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, enums

In my .NET 7 app I configure snake case upper as json string enum converter using Yoh.Text.Json.NamingPolicies version 1.0.0:

```
            _ = services.AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicies.SnakeCaseUpper));
                }) ...
```

It works well in message bodies.

But when it comes to using an enum as query parameter, the upper snake case value is not recognized as a valid value of the enum and results in an error status.
Ok, a query parameter is not a json. But how can I configure my .NET Api to accept upper snake case for enum values in query parameters?

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserDto>> Get([FromQuery]UserStatus? userStatus) { ... }
```

UserStatus Enum (in angular client):

```
export enum UserStatus {
  ACTIVE = "ACTIVE",
  AWAITING_ROLE_ASSIGNMENT = "AWAITING_ROLE_ASSIGNMENT",
  AWAITING_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = "AWAITING_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION"
}
```

The "ACTIVE" value works correctly. Only the values which contain an underscore are not recognized by the model binder.